# I have an array and I put them in table, I need to change background color of table

Tags: php, html, css

I need to have rows with value less than 50000 background red color, more than 100000 background blue color and others have no color. Problem is that it is taking a general color which is written in "else" part. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$lll = array("blank" => 46822,
              "default" => 79254,
              "display" => 49511,
              "document" => 88839,
              "examples" => 81802,
              "for" => 52427,
              "function" => 65907,
              "height" => 47510,
              "left" => 45011,
              "literal" => 45884,
              "reference" => 61932,
              "tag" => 148895,
              "target" => 339410,
              "this" => 45275,
              "title" => 91441,
              "top" => 335154,
              "type" => 65768,
              "width" => 68883);    
foreach ($lll as $key => $value)
        {
            if($value < 50000)
            {
                $color = "#FF0000";
            }
            else if($value > 100000)
            {
                $color = "#0012FF";
            }
            else
            {
                $color = "#FFFFFF";
            }
        }
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Web page</title>
    <style>
        td{background-color: <?php echo $color;?>}
        tr{background-color: <?php echo $color;?>}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "<table border = '1'>";
        echo "<td>Number</td><td>Value</td>";
            foreach ($lll as $key => $value)
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$key</td>";
                echo "<td>$value</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your initial loop (`$color` *setter*) will simply traverse through the array and assign the last array key/value to `$color`, which happens to be *between* 50,000 and 100,000 (68883), which satisfies your final `else` statement.

Comment: Are each of your array keys a specific page or something? So if you're on page *display*, for example, you'd want `$color = "#FF0000";`? I'm not understanding your setup here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this maybe?

*Side note; since I don't know PHP, I assume its syntax is correct*

```
<?php
$lll = array("blank" => 46822,
              "default" => 79254,
              "display" => 49511,
              "document" => 88839,
              "examples" => 81802,
              "for" => 52427,
              "function" => 65907,
              "height" => 47510,
              "left" => 45011,
              "literal" => 45884,
              "reference" => 61932,
              "tag" => 148895,
              "target" => 339410,
              "this" => 45275,
              "title" => 91441,
              "top" => 335154,
              "type" => 65768,
              "width" => 68883);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Web page</title>
    <style>
        .red   {background-color: #F00;}
        .blue  {background-color: #0012FF;}
        .white {background-color: #FFF;} 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "<table border = '1'>";
        echo "<tr><td>Number</td><td>Value</td></tr>";
            foreach ($lll as $key => $value)
            {
              if($value < 50000)
              {
                echo "<tr class='red'>";
              }
              else if($value > 100000)
              {
                echo "<tr class='blue'>";
              }
              else
              {
                echo "<tr class='white'>";
              }
              echo "<td>$key</td>";
              echo "<td>$value</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```